# Does the pandas dataframe changes if I use it as an argument to a function and return the dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am passing a dataframe as an argument to a function which performs column and row filtration and then returns the dataframe, now I am storing the return value of  function in a different dataframe, In such case the original dataframe will remain unchanged or not?

```
def some_function(df):
  #row and column filter on df
  return df

new_df=some_function(original_df)
```

Will "new_df" be equal to "original_df"?

**In my personal experience sometimes the original dataframe remains the same and sometimes it changes. What is the reason behind such behavior?**

Comment: In your example it always equals to the  function output. Perhaps some functions do not change the DF. Sometimes you have to enter `inplace=True` options to make change. Please post examples of functions not changing the DF so we'd comment on specifics.

Comment: I think this problem is related to [Returning a view versus a copy](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy)

Answer (score 5):

When you pass a pandas dataframe as an argument, you pass it *by reference*. This means that the function *can* change the dataframe (`df`, in your case). Now:

- It *can* change `df`, but it doesn't necessarily do so. In the following example, df doesn't change:

```
def foo(df):
    print(df)
```

- when it returns `df` at the end, the object it returns may or may not be the same object as the original object. Operations like `df["new_col"] = 7` or `df.reset_index(inplace=True)` change the original dataframe. Operations such as `df = df * 2` create a new dataframe, so when you return `df` at the end of the function it's a different object than the one it received as an argument.